# Which nodes are active in a multi-subnet failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

I have previously worked with FCI where there are 2 nodes. 1 server is active and other service is not active. Both share the same disk. If node 1 or sql server service on node 1 goes down, then it starts up the sql server service on node 2.

In a multi-subnet failover cluster, which of the below nodes are active and which are passive?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/sql-server-multi-subnet-clustering-sql-server) you copied that image from, that is a single stretch cluster spanning multiple subnets. It’s not possible to say from the image which would be the primary, beyond only saying one of the 4 could be the primary at a time.

In simple terms, other than the fact it spans multiple subnets and has storage replicated, it would still act like a traditional FCI in that only one node is primary at a time.